# Developing a customized caffe-based Convolutional Neural Network from scratch

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, caffe2

I like to develop a new Convolutional Neural Network from scratch and [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/transfer-learning-the-art-of-fine-tuning-a-pre-trained-model/) found a discussion how to use pre-trained model for a new network.
There are four categories and if the training image size is small and data similarity is low, we need to freeze the initial K layers and train the later N-K layers. That discussion used VGG16 as example. Say the new Network is based on VGG16, we can use VGG16 pre-trained model.
But I like to have new structure of Network as below. Network is a small network with 6 layers only. I have only 1200 training images only.

How can I start for this new network?

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "pool4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "conv6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "conv6"
}
layer {
  name: "pool6"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "pool6"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copy the reply from [there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353355/developing-a-new-convolution-neural-network-from-scratch) for those facing similar issues.

```
You do not need a pre-trained model. Actually, when you are developing your own, custom architecture, you cannot even get a pre-trained model.

1200 images is not much, but without any other information, one cannot tell if it is enough or not. Maybe your problem is simple, your network small and the dataset will be enough. Maybe your problem is tough and even 109 images would not be enough. There is no simple answer to that.

Also, there is no simple answer to which of the two options will be better. I would start training from scratch, using augmented dataset. Ideally, generate the augmented versions on the fly rather than creating a fixed amount (e.g. 18) from each image. If you observe poor performance, pre-train on VOC and then fine-tune on your own data (but still use augmentation). This is the only way to compare which is better.

As final remarks, I would recommend this article summarizing some good tips for neural network development and debugging; and this thread focused on learning problems.
```